# Integration notation question parenthesis meaning

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have an integral whose notation I'd like to ask about. Say I have a definite integral
$\int_0^{bc_{max}}\frac{dA(bc)}{dbc}  dbc$ 
My question is what do the parenthesis mean? My thinking is that A is a const. and that you integrate over bc. Or is it that bc is a funcion of A?

bc in this case is an energy that runs from 0 to it's maximum value and A is the flux through a surface.

Comment: I feel like this is one of those things that depends on the context in which this popped up. You might have to explain where the integral came from, how it was derived, and all that to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Yes, as it is it is very unclear.

Comment: It seems to be integrating $bc$, but $bc$ is also the upper limit of the integration! Thus, the integral doesn't make much sense to me as it's currently written and I'm interpreting it.

Comment: I take it to mean that $A$ is a function of the variable $bc$. It says, differentiate $A$ with respect to $bc$, then antidifferentiate with respect to $bc$, then evaluate between $0$ and $bc$. But it might help if you had an actual example you could point to.

Comment: The upper limit should be bc_max. I have edited to show this.

Comment: I found the equation in another source  with a better explanation and A is a function of bc.

Comment: Like I said. So, is there still aanything left unanswered here?

Comment: So $bc$ is not a product?   This is really confusing.

Comment: @Randall Perhaps the $bc$ is meant to be $b_c$ instead, but was not formatted properly. Otherwise, I agree using $2$ letters together as a variable, especially without using appropriate brackets, is very confusing.

Comment: bc is a product

Comment: If there's nothing left unanswered, Surf, maybe you'd like to write up what you've learned here, and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above I found the equation in question in another source with a clear explanation that A was a function of the product bc.